# How to use JWT Token at Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, jwt

I am using the Heroku to up my back-end. At my back-end, I have one route that it is to log in to the application. So when I log at my application, it is created the `JWT TOKEN` in this format.

```
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0ZUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ0eXBlIjoiZmlzIiwiaWF0IjoxNTkwMTU3NzA4fQ.dpGRBog-KfVqd4PknxeLmjNCfT1zBodscJ6OO9Fg8do
```

Some routes at my application need to check if the user are logged, verify one function that I have called `passport.authenticate()` it is a middleware. And I would like to know how can I use to heroku to test my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to !!!test the application!!! you can use environment variables (since these variables are usually constants and are not usually changed!). You can set `TOKEN` in the config vars section in Heroku, and can use `process.env.TOKEN` to acccess that generated token!

Complete documentation here on how to set config vars: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

And if you don't want this additional overhead of setting up config vars, you can just create a `.json` file (upload along with other app files) that contains the generated token ,and just require that json file and use the token stored in there.